# AWS spot instance "invalid" error

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to use the AWS spot instance market to cheaply spin up a high performance sever for some machine learning work. I went through the spot instance management console, filled out various options, and on the last page when I try to click "Launch" I get the following error message:

```
Invalid: (InstanceType: c4.8xlarge,Os: generic,Addressing: nat)
```

That's all the message said, so it's not clear to me what's wrong. I don't think I made any unusual specifications. Is my permutation of instance type, AMI, and addressing incorrect? If so, why? How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Did you check the below answer?

Comment: @error2007s, I tried your answer just now, and it works. I do still want to know why it works though.

Comment: That is some bug from AWS side I guess as it works for all except for this type pf instance.

Answer (score 1):

That is happening because you are not selecting the subnet while you are creating the instance I too faced the same problem for "c4.8xlarge" I don't know if this is a bug or some thing else but you have to specify the zone and subnet for this type of instance and then the requests goes through. Check this screenshot below.

[image]